# Qt Network chat Example

Tags: qt

I am running network-chat example in QtCreator, I just run one Instance of program and without closing it running another one, but they are not chatting, nor each dialog showing Presence of another. Pls tell me what is the problems.

Comment: There is no error as such, but two chat instance should chat, or if the problem in my way running the code, then, pls suggest the right way.

Comment: The program I am telling about, is Qt/examples/networking/Network-chat,  which you can found in qtCeator statUp.

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows, did a dialog pop up to allow network access for the application?

Comment: I am using Fedora14, and a popup of chat window comes with each instance og Chat program.

Comment: Hey, I installed Qt-Creator 2.2 RC, and in this version, there is no Network Chat Example?????